# JavaScript - for Loop vs. Array shift

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, shift

I have two functions, they do look alike but what I don't really understand is when inside the `for`-loop, since the input is an array, why doesn't the array need any index to call the first array?

I have an array of...

```
var puzzlers = [
function(a) { return 8 * a - 10; },
function(a) { return (a - 3) * (a - 3) * (a - 3); },
function(a) { return a * a + 4; },
function(a) { return a % 5; }
];
```

I'm trying to loop through the array with an input. The result of the first function will then be used as the next function's input then the first array will be removed.

This is what I wrote...

```
function applyAndEmpty(input, queue)
{
    var length = queue.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        input = queue[0](input);
        queue.shift();
    }
    return input;
}
```

The above does give me the answer but then I see that there's another way of writing it which is

```
var applyAndEmpty = function(input, queue)
{
    var length = queue.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        input = queue.shift()(input);
    }
    return input;
};
```

What I don't understand is the part `input = queue.shift()(input)`.

Doesn't the `queue` need an index?

Comment: No. If you know what `shift()` does - And that's executing a function from your array and removing it from the Array stack.

Comment: `shift()` removes the first element in the array and returns it. It's inefficient though for what you're doing.

Comment: @4castle omg! thx thx I totally forgot that it returns the element that it doesn't just remove it. totally got it thx thx a lot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So you're basically asking what `shift` does and here you go:
What you can do using `for(var i=0;`... you can do using `shift()` (quite similar but not!)

#### Using `for` loop (and `index`)

```js
var array = [
  function(){return "a";},
  function(){return "b";}
];
  
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    console.log( array[i]() );  
    // "a"
    // "b"
}

console.log(array.length); //2       !!Still there!!!
```

#### Using `shift()` (and `while` for example)

```js
var array = [
  function(){return "a";},
  function(){return "b";}
];
  
while(array.length){                // while array has length
    console.log( array.shift()() );  // execute and remove from array
    // "a"
    // "b"
}

console.log(array.length); //0   !!!Empty array due to shift()!!!
```

So basically it removes a key from your Array and returns it.
As long as that array has *keys* it will loop until it's empty.

**The difference between the two is drastic:**
**The `for` loop in example 1.** will loop but not alter your original array.
**Using `shift()` in example 2.** you're (using and) **removing** your Array keys one by one.

Read more about Array manipulation:

[Array.prototype.shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)  `1 <-- [2,3,4]`
[Array.prototype.unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)  `5 --> [5,2,3,4]`
[Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)  `[5,2,3,4,6] <-- 6`
[Array.prototype.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)  `[5,2,3,4] --> 6`

and other Methods

Comment: I like your first explanation more which directly answered how the `shift()` returns and removes the element.  Thx for the eanswer~

Comment: Is there a purpose for the double-parenthesis after `shift()()` or is it a typo? I don't want to blindly edit out a syntax I didn't know about.

Comment: @Adamlive `array.shift()` does just a shift without executing the actual key function. `array.shift()()` instead shifts **and** executes the function (which is returned thanks to `shift()` from out `array` of functions). - Logically, if your array does not contains functions the second parens couple is not needed

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Ah, I did not read the question very well. I skipped to your answer because it was so clean and neatly formatted and had the info I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can simplify the logic using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Here how you can do that:

```
var puzzlers = [
function(a) { return 8 * a - 10; },
function(a) { return (a - 3) * (a - 3) * (a - 3); },
function(a) { return a * a + 4; },
function(a) { return a % 5; }
];

function runPuzzler(inputValue){
   return puzzlers.reduce(function(prev, curr){
       return curr(prev);
   },inputValue);
}
```

Output :

```
EachArrayValues::100
EachArrayValues::200
EachArrayValues::0
EachArrayValues::400
EachArrayValues::500
EachArrayValues::-50
Negative value found, ie -50
```